# Inconsistent strtotime

Tags: php

I dont understand why this is happening

```
echo date('l F y',strtotime('next Tuesday',time())) . "\n";
echo date('l F y',strtotime('next Wednesday',time())) . "\n";
echo date('l F y',strtotime('next Thursday',time())) . "\n";
echo date('l F y',strtotime('next Friday',time())) . "\n";
```

gives me

```
Tuesday October 12
Wednesday October 12
Thursday October 12
Friday October 12
```

Why?

Comment: What do you expect it to give you?

Comment: Seems pretty consistent to me.

Comment: (hint: the y in that string means the last two digits of the year. Maybe you wanted d?)

Comment: Damit. Thats what 16 hours straight does to you. Thanks.

Comment: @Dainis Abols - neither is yours

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking it to output the day of the week, followed by the month, followed by the last two digits of the year, which is what it is doing.

Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for a list of the date format characters and what they mean.

Answer (score 3):

As @jrdn said, the `y` is for year, so you are getting the year of the next Tuesday etc.

For the date use this:

```
echo date('l F d',strtotime('next Tuesday',time())) . "\n";
echo date('l F d',strtotime('next Wednesday',time())) . "\n";
echo date('l F d',strtotime('next Thursday',time())) . "\n";
echo date('l F d',strtotime('next Friday',time())) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
Tuesday October 30
Wednesday October 31
Thursday October 25
Friday October 26
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add d format it will be more clear

```
echo date('d l F y',strtotime('next Tuesday',time())) . "\n";
echo date('d l F y',strtotime('next Wednesday',time())) . "\n";
echo date('d l F y',strtotime('next Thursday',time())) . "\n";
echo date('d l F y',strtotime('next Friday',time())) . "\n";
```

will o/p

```
30 Tuesday October 12 // next tuesday date since this week tuesday has already passed
31 Wednesday October 12 // next wed date since this week wed has already passed
25 Thursday October 12 // next thur date since this week thur is yet to pass
26 Friday October 12 // next fri date since this week fri is yet to pass
```

read more about [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out?

```
<?php
$nexTuesday = date('l F y',strtotime('next Tuesday',time())) . "\n";
$nextWednesday = date('l F y',strtotime('next Wednesday',time())) . "\n";
$nextThursday = date('l F y',strtotime('next Thursday',time())) . "\n";
$nextFriday = date('l F y',strtotime('next Friday',time())) . "\n";

//Lets make date to time

$nexTuesday = strtotime($nexTuesday);
$nextWednesday = strtotime($nextWednesday);
$nextThursday = strtotime($nextThursday);
$nextFriday = strtotime($nextFriday);

//If you have need for this, then echo the timestamp as 'l F y' like this:

echo date('l F y',$nextFriday);
?>
```